# Outbound URL Redirect Rule to serve content request from an Azure CDN not working

Tags: asp.net, redirect, azure

I wrote a redirect rule that will route client's content requests, to the linked Azure CDN serving my hosted ASP.Net MVC website on an Standard plan.

I tried several iteration of the rule; nothing is working

These are the steps I took to implementation

1. Create Storage
2. Create CDN ENDPOINT http:// azxxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net/
3. Created a subdomain at GoDaddy verified and pointing to azxxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net/
4. Created a public container using Cloudberry Explorer
5. Uploaded images blobs to the container and
6. Tested content availability successfully on the browser at http:// azxxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net/images/test.jpeg
7. Tested content availability successfully on the browser at https:// storage.blob.core.windows.net/images/test.jpeg
8. inserted the Rewrite-redirect rule on the site web.config file

   ```
     <rewrite>
          <rules>
               <rule name="CDN Redirection" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^images/(.*)" />
                  <action type="Redirect" url="http:// azxxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net/images/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
           </rules>
      </rewrite>
   ```

   ......( No using the custom subdomain name yet waiting for propagation)
9. Save, stop and restart website, clear cache, F12, inspect element .....nothing, content still being pulled straight up from the website 
   So what am I doing wrong?

Check my website at http://www.ehubcap.net

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple rule that is tested and works on Azure Websites:

```
  <rule name="images redirection" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="images/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://double.blob.core.windows.net/images/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

Note, you don't need the `^` in your match pattern. 
You can check the result [here](https://double.azurewebsites.net/) - check the original page source first - IMG element refers to a local image: http://double.azurewebsites.net/images/some.jpg, which is being redirected by the URL Rewrite to the blob storage (you can redirect to any domain you wish).

Note, however, that URL Rewrite module is dependent on other modules. For best results, the UrlRewrite Module should be the first module to process the result. If you have enabled static and/or dynamic compression to compress the output, the URL rewrite will not work. This is because the default configuration kicks the compression module first, then brings the URL Rewrite module. And the URL Rewrite module cannot read compressed content. Yeah, don't ask me  why. So, first disable compression (if you have enabled it) to check the URL rewrite config. Then try to reorder the modules. The simplest would be to first remove them, next add the URL Rewrite and then Compression module.